# Polyglossia; Arabic font found

Tags: fonts, fontspec, polyglossia

I have TeX Live 2017 installed on a macOS Sierra.

I get an error when I compile this simple document.

```
%% XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

% Setting a font
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

Hello, and this is an Arabic Hello \textarabic{ﻡﺮﺤﺑﺍ}


\end{document}
```

The Error;

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Amiri" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.8 ...fontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

?
```

How can I install fonts in `Polyglossia`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XeLaTeX` uses system fonts, so, if you don't have `Amiri` on your computer, then you need to [download](https://www.amirifont.org/) it and put it into your computer's font folder.

Also, shouldn't it be `مرحبا`, not `ﻡﺮﺤﺑﺍ`?

Comment: 'Also, shouldn't it be مرحبا, not ﻡﺮﺤﺑﺍ?' this is becuase It have copied from the terminal.

Comment: But, but it is as you have just said, Thank You So Much